# How to make libcurl install only shared library

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

I m building libcurl with autoconf.

I want to make libcurl install only the shared library (.so).

I do no want that the install copy libcurl.a neither the curl command and config neither the man and other files.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to first install the entire lot in a temporary place, then you move the specific files you need into the correct and final destination.

Like this:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make DESTDIR=/tmp/temp-install install
```

Then you pick the files you want from the `/tmp/temp-install` tree.

Alternatively, you first build everything (possibly with `--disable-static` to skip the static libs) and then run `make install` in the lib directory only:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ cd lib
$ make install
```

Comment: I build libcurl in a cross compile SDK. The ./configure, make and make install are executed automatically by the SDK

Comment: So, you don't want to change anything but still magically affect what gets installed?